# How can we poll the stack status - unused (available) memory

Tags: c, windows, winapi, stack

How can we get this information? I guess it is OS dependent, and I'm running Windows so my question refers to the windows API.

Is there any function that can do that for us - get the remaining stack memory for the calling thread?

Alternatively, if we could find out the following details, we will be able to calculate that on our own:

1. *Get the thread stack base address*. There must be some function that takes a thread identifier as a parameter, and returns some information about it (Such as... Stack base address?)
2. *Get the thread stack size*. If the thread was started by us, we can know it (Since we specified it when calling `CreateThread`). But if it is the main thread, which was started by the OS for our program, or any other thread we did not start explicitly, how do we find it?
3. *Get the current stack pointer*. Well, that's easier. we can either check it with `esp`, or take the address of a local variable, to get a close location.

This is for educational purposes, but I guess it could be used to stop a recursive algorithm from causing a stack overflow - Instead of using any max-depth limiting function.

Comment: Note that [the Itanium has *two stacks*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/04/21/410397.aspx). So far, everybody is looking only at the local variable stack, but there is also the register stack (which is where return addresses go, among other things). So this technique is not sufficient to prevent stack overflow because you're checking only one of the stacks.

Comment: Interesting... But if this "register stack" is actually *hardware* dependent, shouldn't Intel or whoever implements it use the regular call stack for local variables allocation if the register stack is full; After all, using registers to store local variables is not a must, isn't it?

Comment: There is no law that says all processors must be like the x86. (And Itanium is hardly the only processor with register windows.)

Comment: @Raymond Chen: The other stack grows upwards, so doesn't it have the same stack "base" as the memory stack (i.e. they're adjacent)? I'm not sure what happens when they get resized though...

Comment: Even if it has the same base, it has a different top.

Comment: It is said here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slavao/archive/2005/03/19/399117.aspx that they have the same base.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use NtCurrentTeb(), which gets you a pointer to the TEB. This has NT_TIB as its first member:

```
typedef struct _NT_TIB
{
     PEXCEPTION_REGISTRATION_RECORD ExceptionList;
     PVOID StackBase;
     PVOID StackLimit;
     PVOID SubSystemTib;
     // ....
} NT_TIB, *PNT_TIB;
```

Comment: Thread Environment Block (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ms686708) from what I'm missing the NT_TIB ... :-(

Comment: @Pete Wilson: Thread environment block, where all kinds of thread-specific data is stored.

Comment: `struct _TEB`, which is returned from `NtCurrentTeb` has no members. You said that the first member is the `NT_TIB`, so I tried casting the pointer returned from `NtCurrentTeb` to `NT_TIB*`, but it yields weird results when accessing the members... Your answer is exactly what I wanted, but how can I use it?

Comment: @Jong: What do you mean by "weird results"?

Comment: @wj32 It makes more sense now. However, `StackLimit - StackBase` gives a *negative* result. Shouldn't it be positive? The result is always `-8192`, or 8KB as the inital stack size, this makes sense. On the other hand, when calculating the difference between a local variable address (in `main`) to `StackBase` or `StackLimit`, the result is 20KB~. Doesn't make sense if the size was 8KB...

Comment: @Jong: Remember that the stack grows down. So sub esp, xxx allocates, not frees. StackBase is the start of the stack - i.e., the memory address above the stack. StackLimit is the lowest address at which you still have committed stack.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly answering the OP's question, but referring to the idea mentioned at it's end: *"... it could be used to stop a recursive algorithm from causing a stack overflow - Instead of using any max-depth limiting function."*

The Windows API offers the method `SetThreadStackGuarantee()` which allows to define a minimum stack size to keep available when throwing a stack overflow exception. This method together with the VC runtime library method `_resetstkoflw()` may make it possible to recover from stack overflows.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89f73td2) on MSDN for details.

Answer (score 1):

1. *Get the thread stack base address*: As [wj32 showed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8683554/161455), use the `StackBase` of the thread information block.
2. *Get the thread stack size*: Determine a threads reserved stack size (which is it's maximum size) is different.  What the `StackLimit` shows is the [lowest commited address](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/archive/s2ce.aspx), which can show how large the stack has ever grown, not it's limit.  Also not that the stack size you pass to `CreateThread` is the initial commit size, not reserve size unless you pass the `STACK_SIZE_PARAM_IS_A_RESERVATION` flag.  Your program's stack size is specified by a [linker parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8cxs58a6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and defaults to 1MB if you don't specify.  So most likely all of threads have a 1MB stack reservation.

   Since last page of the [stack is a guard page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686774.aspx) you could conceivably start from the `StackPage` and check each lower stack page `VirtualQuery` to find the gaurd page that would be the end of the stack.  This is of course completely relying on implementation defined behavior.
3. *Get the current stack pointer*:  You could use the `StackLimit` to get the maximum commited size of your stack, but that's not the same as the current pointer.  `esp` is obviously the current stack position and could be higher than `StackLimit`.

Note on reserved vs commited.  In Windows reserved means that virtual addresses have been reserved for use and can't be taken for something else.  Reserved addresses do not consume any physical or virtual memory.  Once it is commited it the address will be mapped to physical or virtual memory and can be used.  Windows user threads have a fixed stack reserve size - address space is reserved for the stack and cannot be increased and a variable commit size - the stack will only use (commit) memory as it needs it.

**Edit**

My thoughts on checking the gaurd page won't work.  I wrote a test program and the guard page is set at the commit limit, so that doesn't work.  But I did find that running a `VirtualQuery` anywhere on the stack will give the `AllocationBase` of the lowest address on the stack, since the reserve size was allocated at once.  The following example shows this in action:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <WinNT.h>
#include <stdio.h>

DWORD GetThreadStackSize()
{
    SYSTEM_INFO systemInfo = {0};
    GetSystemInfo(&systemInfo);

    NT_TIB *tib = (NT_TIB*)NtCurrentTeb();
    DWORD_PTR stackBase = (DWORD_PTR)tib->StackBase;

    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi = {0};
    if (VirtualQuery((LPCVOID)(stackBase - systemInfo.dwPageSize), &mbi, sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION)) != 0)
    {
        DWORD_PTR allocationStart = (DWORD_PTR)mbi.AllocationBase;
        return stackBase - allocationStart;
    }
    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI ThreadRtn(LPVOID param)
{
    DWORD stackSize = GetThreadStackSize();
    printf("%d\n", stackSize);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    ThreadRtn(NULL);
    HANDLE thread1 = CreateThread(NULL, 65535, ThreadRtn, NULL, 0, NULL);
    WaitForSingleObject(thread1, -1);
    HANDLE thread2 = CreateThread(NULL, 65535, ThreadRtn, NULL, STACK_SIZE_PARAM_IS_A_RESERVATION, NULL);
    WaitForSingleObject(thread2, -1);

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

> 1048576 
>   1048576
>   65536

As it should.

Comment: Works, indeed. And I managed to make a few more tests with it, such as how many bytes a method takes and how many bytes remain on the stack at a given point.

Answer (score -1):

**edit:** This is an outstandingly excellent question for educational purposes! Have an upvote for that. Stack space is fixed **edit:** at the point that a process or thread begins execution; I think you must mean the heap, from which memory is dynamically allocated (by malloc( ), for example. There's a good discussion of this question over here  [**on MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810603.aspx). I don't see the exact API call you're looking for: you'll have to poke around for that; it can't be too far away.

HTH

Comment: When calling `CreateThread` you can specify the thread's stack size. Maybe the space is fixed once it is determined, but each thread may have another stack size. .NET threads have usually ~1MB stacks, usual threads of a C program have 64KB I think. I have done many experiments with different sizes, even 1 gigabyte (The maximum windows allowed was 1.4GB), which lets you do.. infinite recursion, pretty much. In short, the stack size is **not** fixed.

Comment: Generally when creating a thread you specify the stack size for that thread. For example if you use pthread_create(), you can pass attributes which include the stack size. You can also get the stack base address and size for the current thread with pthread_attr_getstackaddr () and pthread_attr_getstacksize (), respectively. I don't know on Windows, though.

Comment: @Jong: Yes. There are really two stack "sizes": reserve and commit. Stacks can be resized easily provided that there is enough address space upwards.

Comment: The `dwStackSize` parameter of `CreateThread()` specifies the *initial* stack size, not the *total* available stack size.  When a thread's stack fills up, the OS allocates more space for the stack until it cannot allocate any more.  This is documentated behavior: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686774.aspx