# Get Stack Reserve Size in Windows C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, stack

An eponymous question. A Visual Studio C++ app (32 and 64-bit) required a larger value for the "Reserve Stack Size" linker property. I'd like to get the apps current value at run-time. How can this be done?

```
printf("Reserve stack size is %d bytes\n", ?);
```

Comment: [GetCurrentThreadStackLimits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706789(v=vs.85).aspx)?  Seems to be Windows 8+ though :/

Comment: Why would you want this information? What are you going to use it for at run-time? Anyway, it's in the PE header, so you can read it by the standard techniques. Consult your copy of Windows Internals for details.

Comment: Forbidden knowledge, you can dig it out of [the TEB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block).

Comment: This SO [Question/Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683335/how-can-we-poll-the-stack-status-unused-available-memory) may help